# How do I add global styles without requiring an extra component?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I want to apply some global styles to my website (body, h1, h2, h3, etc).

To do this with Angular2, the [view encapsultation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html) of a component needs to be set thusly: `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`.

example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: template(),
  styleUrls: ['global.scss', 'app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello world!';
}
```

The problem is that this encapsulation rule applies to *all* of this components stylesheets, which means I must have a separate component just for global styles.

Is there another way to do this without requiring an extra component and without needing to edit Angular-CLI's build config?

(I'm using `angular/core 2.0.0-rc.5` and `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`)

Comment: Why don't you just add a global stylesheet in your index.html? I mean, the style stuff is nice and shiny but it's nothing special which you HAVE to use.

Comment: Because Angular-CLI doesn't detect that, and thus doesn't include it in builds. Unless I'm mistaken, all resources must be imported or referenced in scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PR mentioned by [drbishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6329719/drbishop) has been merged and released as `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`.

To upgrade from `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2` to `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`, run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3
```

Note: if you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...` errors on running `ng version` after upgrading you may need to upgrade to Node.js 6. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1883 for details.

If you generate a new project using `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`, you can add a `styles.css` file to your `src` directory which will be automatically included in your build. You can also add external CSS imports to the `apps[0].styles` property of `angular-cli.json`.

Your `angular-cli.json` should look something like this for a new project generated by `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3`:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3",
    "name": "demo"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "lazyRoutePrefix": "+"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that, as of this comment's date, `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` is the current version.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently being designed and will be implemented before a final release. The general idea will be to provide a reference to a style file (CSS/SCSS/LESS...) and have it included within the application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, it's being implemented for future releases. There's already a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1633) to fix this. You can update it manually as a workaround for now.

Then, update your `angular-cli.json` file:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "mobile": false,
      "additionalEntries": [
        { "input": "polyfills.ts", "output": "polyfills.js" },
        "styles.sass"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
```